# Why the program fails without try/catch?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

I use VS2010 and C++ in release config

The following executed okay:

```
int status;
try
{
    status = myfunction(arg1, arg2);
}
catch (int e)
{
    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << endl;
}
```

However, the following crashed the program:

```
int status;
status = myfunction(arg1, arg2);
```

What happened?
I do not have the source of the method, myfunction, which is part of a third party dll.

Comment: Presumably it's because `myfunction` throws an exception.

Comment: It's not even going to compile if you declare a variable called `statis` and initialise one called `status`...

Comment: My guess is that myfunction causes a crash, maybe because it doesn't like being passed the same thing for two arguments.  If I'm right you owe me $1million for wasting my ESP on you rather than the JREF challenge.

Comment: Body of `myfunction()` seems to be missing from this question.

Comment: @Griwes: and it's unlikely we'll ever get it: "I do not have the source of the method, myfunction, which is part of a third party dll."

Comment: Sorry guys, typo fixed. arg1 arg2. I guess, the reason is that the myfunction did its thing and before it came back, it threw an exception. So to me, the myfunction was executing ok because it gave me the correct answer - writing some files etc. Thank you for the hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By removing the try/catch block, you do not catch an exception that is thrown when the function is called.  This causes the uncaught exception to wind up the stack all the way to `main()` and since it is still unhandled, exit the program

From the oputput it seems the thrown integer is a code for what error happened exactly.  To see if this can be reconciled, you need to look up the error code.